# How to deploy my ASP.Net site to Linux?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, deployment

I have `ASP.Net 4.6` site using `MVC 6`. This site is already built with `MS SQL Server`. But in the new version, the database is replaced with `MySql`
The site is running fine on my local windows machine.As Microsoft has named this version `ASP.Net VNext - Open Source`.

Currently, this site is deployed on `windows` server of Bigrock hosting provider.

Now I have another subscription with Bluehost for `Linux` Server.

But I have no clue how to deploy the same site on Linux server.

Can somebody guide me Step by Step to deploy the `published site` on `Linux`

Comment: If you want to publish .NET Core site, Scott's article here may help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx.

Comment: just for clarification. Is it ASP.NET 4.6? Or ASP.NET Core? ASP.NET 4.6 needs Mono installed on the machine. ASP.NET Core runs on Kestrel using the .NET Core runtime

Comment: @JuergenGutsch It is ASP.Net 4.6

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/202615/asp-net-4-0-on-mod-mono